@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function in observers/collect in Jetpack Compose
I'm new to Jetpack Compose and I'm facing an issue with implementing a button click. My scenario is as follows: I need to call an API when a button is clicked and update the UI once the response is received. While the API call is happening, I need to show a loader. However, I'm encountering the error "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function." Below is a screenshot of my issue.

Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance

The collectLatest lambda is executed every time the tokenState flow emits a new value. That's incompatible to Compose, so you cannot use CircularProgressIndicator() here (hence the error). Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] in text form, then we can see how this can be rewritten.


if you check Button component document you will see onClick parameter is not allow composable lamda like onClick: @Composable () -> Unit use a mutableState variable for show loading bar:
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue

var loading: Boolean by remember{ mutableStateOf(false) }    
Button(
        enabled = enabled,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        onClick = { if (!loading) onClick() },
        colors = colors
    ) {
        Row(
            Modifier,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            if (loading) {
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color = colors.contentColor,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(30.dp)
                        .progressSemantics()
                )
            } else {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    text = text, // write your text
                    maxLines = 1
                )
            }
        }

My advice create a function for it for Example:
fun PrimaryButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    loadingSize: Dp = 32.dp,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    loading: Boolean = false,
    colors: ButtonColors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors().copy(
        contentColor = Colors.White,
        disabledContainerColor = Color.Gray,
        containerColor = Color.Blue,
        disabledContentColor = Color.White
    ),
    text: String,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    ) {
    Button(
        enabled = enabled,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .then(modifier),
        onClick = {
            if (!loading)
                onClick()
        },
        colors = colors
    ) {
        Row(
            Modifier,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            if (loading) {
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color = colors.contentColor,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(loadingSize)
                        .progressSemantics()
                )
            } else {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    text = text,
                    maxLines = 1
                )
            }
        }

    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun PrimaryButtonPreview() {
    PrimaryButton(modifier = Modifier, text = "Button") {}
}

